# combine 2 df with a for loop to make projections

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, projection

I have 2 data frames, both with strings, dates, and numbers. df1 is data for 2020 and df2 is data for 2021-2025. I will use df2 (column H) as a growth rate on df1. I need to multiply all numbers of df1 (columns D, E, F) by df2 (H[i,]) for each year in df2, from 2021 to 2025.

I have structured a function, but I am still thinking about how to address it.
Could you please check my code and provide me with some ideas to complete the function?
I really appreciate your help.

```
df1 <- read.csv("df1.csv", check.names=FALSE)
df2 <- read.csv("df2.csv", check.names=FALSE)

df1:
A   B   year    D   E   F
abc ab  2020    0   1   2
def cd  2020    3   4   0
ghi ef  2020    0   5   6
jkl gh  2020    7   8   0
mno ij  2020    0   9   10

df2: 
year    H
2021    1.1
2022    1.2
2023    1.3
2024    1.4
2025    1.5

df3 <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(df2)){
  df3 = rbind(df1, df2 %>% 
        mutate(df1$all_columns_with_numbers = all_columns_with_numbers[i,] * df2$H[i,] ))
}
df3

A    B     C    D    E      F
abc ab  2021    0    1.1    2.2
abc ab  2022    3.6  4.8    0
abc ab  2023    0    6.5    7.8
abc ab  2024    9.8  11.2   0
abc ab  2025    0    13.5   15
def cd  2021    …    …      …
```

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow! About to go to bed so cannot do it now, but one way of doing this would be to do a cross join relationship many to many and then the mutate as in your for loop

Comment: @Mark how did OP get the second row?

Comment: Could you explain how you got `abc ab 2022 3.6,...` ie the second row?

Comment: @Onyambu your guess is as good as mine. I think it might just be a typo- see their code

Comment: @Mark I could swear OP just multiplied the second row of df1 with the second row of df2, but the issue is that the second row of df1 is `def cd` and not `abc ab`

Comment: @mark you do not have `abc ab 2022 3.6 ...` in your solution. Your solution is an easy one. a quick one actually in base R

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait and see what OP says about the mysterious 3.6 ...

Comment: @Mark yeah. if it was a cross join one could do `as.matrix(df1[4:6])%x%  df2$H` which will give the exact results as yours. The problem is the first two columns. There is no way to get what OP wants

Comment: @Onyambu I had another go at it...hoping that is what OP wants (it fits more what they say they wanted in their question, despite the lack of a crossjoin

Comment: @Mark, your solution still has all values for column D for the groups `abc ab` as 0.

Comment: @Onyambu you're right- it's not right, but without more details I don't think we can know what is going on. Nothing like a somewhat vague question to make you feel stupid 

Comment: tks both, @Onyambu, yes you're right... it was a typo at the 3.6... :) but both answers are perfect... for the second one, I was thinking to add df1 at the end of the calculations, but now it is great to have it inside the function. Much appreciate it.

Comment: dear both, just in case I upgraded this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76647324/combine-2-df-to-make-projections-using-previous-result-of-the-cross-join-and-gro). I did not consider the previous incremental value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're wanting to do is a kind of [cross join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/cross-join), followed by mutiplying the columns D, E, and F by H. That is shown below:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
    select(-year) %>%
    cross_join(df2) %>%
    # multiply columns D, E, F by H
    mutate(across(c(D, E, F), ~ . * H)) %>%
    select(-H)

# A tibble: 25 × 6
   A     B         D     E     F  year
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1 abc   ab      0     1.1   2.2  2021
 2 abc   ab      0     1.2   2.4  2022
 3 abc   ab      0     1.3   2.6  2023
 4 abc   ab      0     1.4   2.8  2024
 5 abc   ab      0     1.5   3    2025
 6 def   cd      3.3   4.4   0    2021
 7 def   cd      3.6   4.8   0    2022
 8 def   cd      3.9   5.2   0    2023
 9 def   cd      4.2   5.6   0    2024
10 def   cd      4.5   6     0    2025
# ℹ 15 more rows
```

Though, after speaking with Onyambu, and reading through your question again, I'm now unsure! Maybe what you want is some way of getting D, E, and F multiplied by H for each year, something like this:

```
grow_year <- function(df) {
    df %>%
    mutate(year = year + 1) %>%
    left_join(df2, by = "year") %>%
    mutate(across(c(D, E, F), ~ . * H)) %>%
    select(-H)
}
y21 <- grow_year(df1)
y22 <- grow_year(y21)
y23 <- grow_year(y22)
y24 <- grow_year(y23)
y25 <- grow_year(y24)

out <- bind_rows(df1, y21, y22, y23, y24, y25)

# A tibble: 30 × 6
   A     B      year     D     E     F
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 abc   ab     2020   0     1     2  
 2 def   cd     2020   3     4     0  
 3 ghi   ef     2020   0     5     6  
 4 jkl   gh     2020   7     8     0  
 5 mno   ij     2020   0     9    10  
 6 abc   ab     2021   0     1.1   2.2
 7 def   cd     2021   3.3   4.4   0  
 8 ghi   ef     2021   0     5.5   6.6
 9 jkl   gh     2021   7.7   8.8   0  
10 mno   ij     2021   0     9.9  11  
# ℹ 20 more rows
```

Comment: `mutate(cross_join(df1[-3], df2), across(D:F)*H, H = NULL)` seems simpler

Comment: yes @Onyambu, it is indeed simpler. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Onyambu it does get into a matter of taste. I was writing my code at 3 a.m., so I wasn't looking to golf it 

Answer (score 1):

R is a vectorized language. Try to find the vectorized solutions. ie avoid `for-loop` unless otherwise necessary. Here is a base R solution:

```
 cbind(df1[rep(seq(n<-nrow(df1)), each = n), 1:2], df2[1],
         as.matrix(df1[4:6]) %x% df2$H)

      A  B year    1    2    3
1   abc ab 2021  0.0  1.1  2.2
1.1 abc ab 2022  0.0  1.2  2.4
1.2 abc ab 2023  0.0  1.3  2.6
1.3 abc ab 2024  0.0  1.4  2.8
1.4 abc ab 2025  0.0  1.5  3.0
2   def cd 2021  3.3  4.4  0.0
2.1 def cd 2022  3.6  4.8  0.0
2.2 def cd 2023  3.9  5.2  0.0
2.3 def cd 2024  4.2  5.6  0.0
2.4 def cd 2025  4.5  6.0  0.0
3   ghi ef 2021  0.0  5.5  6.6
3.1 ghi ef 2022  0.0  6.0  7.2
3.2 ghi ef 2023  0.0  6.5  7.8
3.3 ghi ef 2024  0.0  7.0  8.4
3.4 ghi ef 2025  0.0  7.5  9.0
4   jkl gh 2021  7.7  8.8  0.0
4.1 jkl gh 2022  8.4  9.6  0.0
4.2 jkl gh 2023  9.1 10.4  0.0
4.3 jkl gh 2024  9.8 11.2  0.0
4.4 jkl gh 2025 10.5 12.0  0.0
5   mno ij 2021  0.0  9.9 11.0
5.1 mno ij 2022  0.0 10.8 12.0
5.2 mno ij 2023  0.0 11.7 13.0
5.3 mno ij 2024  0.0 12.6 14.0
```